# Taking derivative on both sides of an equation

Tags: calculus

What theorem or rule is used for this:

$x = f(\theta)$

$dx = f'(\theta) d\theta$

I would have expected $dx = f'(\theta)$

Thanks

Comment: $dx=f'(\theta )$ has no sense. Nevertheless, $\frac{dx}{d\theta }=f'(\theta )\implies dx=f'(\theta )d\theta $.

Comment: Chain rule: $dx=f'(\theta)d\theta$.

Comment: The chain rule!

Comment: $dx= f'(\theta)$ makes no sense because "dx" is a **differential** while "$f'(\theta)$ is a **derivative**. They cannot be equal.  Since you were  specifically asked for a "derivative" and not a "differential", Surb's $\frac{dx}{d\theta}= f'(\theta)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

x is a function of theta.

So a tiny change in x (dx) must equal the instantaneous rate of change (slope) of the function of theta times the tiny change of theta (dtheta).

You can think of it as literally just the slope formula with infinitesimals.